# Pandas: shift values from one column to other, and drop duplicates using python

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I am getting a dataframe like this:

```
Name            value
Umicore         470
889 
19  
912 
1.68    
    
Shopify         19
500 
17  
51  
1.44
```

How do get a dataframe such that I will be left with this output

```
Name            value
Umicore         1.68    
Shopify         1.44
```

This is how I am getting my dataframe:

```
#my_df['Name'].replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
#my_df['Name'].replace('', np.nan).ffill(inplace=True) #tried just now fails
#my_df['value'].replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
#my_df.dropna(subset=['Name', 'value'], inplace=True)
my_df.drop_duplicates(keep='last', inplace=True)
my_df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

How do I shift the numbers from Name column to Value column? Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
#if empty strings or NaNs in Name column remove these rows
df['Name'] = df['Name'].replace('', np.nan)
df = df.dropna(subset=['Name'])

#create default index
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)    

print (df)
      Name  value
0  Umicore  470.0
1      889    NaN
2       19    NaN
3      912    NaN
4     1.68    NaN
5  Shopify   19.0
6      500    NaN
7       17    NaN
8       51    NaN
9     1.44    NaN
```

---

```
#convert values to numeric, if no numeric is NaN created
s = pd.to_numeric(df['Name'], errors='coerce')
#forward filling missing values by non numeric values
df['Name'] = df['Name'].where(s.isna()).ffill()
#set value by s
df['value'] = s

print (df)
      Name   value
0  Umicore     NaN
1  Umicore  889.00
2  Umicore   19.00
3  Umicore  912.00
4  Umicore    1.68 <- last value of Umicore
5  Shopify     NaN
6  Shopify  500.00
7  Shopify   17.00
8  Shopify   51.00
9  Shopify    1.44

#remove duplicates by Name column
df = df.drop_duplicates('Name',keep='last')
print (df)
      Name  value
4  Umicore   1.68
9  Shopify   1.44
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, its actually missing value '1.68'

Comment: @technophile_3 - what value is in `value` instead `1.68` in your data output?

Comment: it is an empty cell

Comment: @technophile_3 - it is `NaN` ? Is used `df['Name'] = df['Name'].replace('', np.nan)
df = df.dropna(subset=['Name'])` before my solution for remove NaNs rows?

Comment: Yes I have used your code. and its not NaN. Also the values are generating as I am selecting the highlighted PDFs. so if I select multiple PDFs then using your code the output has lot many empty cells and only the last two cells get filled with the values.

Comment: @technophile_3 - hmm, so data are different like in question? Is possible change them for see where is problem?

Comment: the code where you have used ```print(df)``` instead of NaN I get None.

Comment: @technophile_3 - It is no problem, pandas processing `None`s and `NaN`s same way.

Comment: getting this error ```ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis``` from my_df['Security Name'] = df['Security Name'].where(s.isna()).ffill()

Comment: @technophile_3 - Can you add `df = df.reset_index(drop=True)` like in edited answer?

Comment: done: still the issue is the same. it misses 1.68 value of Umicore. however the other value is perfect!

Comment: @technophile_3 - one idea - is possible `Umicore` there multiple times?

Comment: @technophile_3 - cannot simulate your problem :(

Comment: Umicore is present only a single time. No issues.

Comment: @technophile_3 - and `print (s)` there is `1.68` ? Is last value, above `Shopify`?